# JSF - Loading UISelectItem list in constructor

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am running an application using JSF2.0 and Primefaces 2.2RC2

I have run the profiler on my project and determined there was a bottleneck coming from a UISelectItems list. The list was being populated like 6 times on each action in my application.

The UISelectItem list was being populated in a getter method called getCountryList() and it looked like this

```
public UISelectItems getCountryList() throws Exception {
    Collection List = new ArrayList();
    List<Countries> c_list = myDao.getCountryList();

    for( QcardCountries c : c_list ) {
       list.add(new SelectItem(c.getCountryId().toString(), c.getCountryName());
    }

    UISelectItems countries = new UISelectItems();
    countries.setValue(list);
    return countries;
}
```

This works when I call in the views like so

```
<f:selectItems binding="#{myBean.countryList}" />
```

but again it is called like 6 times for each button or action I make in the application.

I then attempted to move the creation of the List into a method that was called on @PostContruct but when I do that the list does not show up when I use

```
 <f:selectItems binding="#{myBean.countryList}" />
```

It just shows up as empty. Does anyone know how to properly create a list so it is only created one time and can be called throughout an entire users session to populate a dropdown list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

org.life.java already gave a hint about loading, but since you're unnecessarily using `binding` and JSF 2.0 provides a way to just take `List<SomeBean>` instead of `List<SelectItem>` as value, here's a complete example how to do it the right way:

```
private List<Country> countries;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    countries = myDao.getCountryList();
}

public List<Country> getCountries() {
    return countries;
}
```

with

```
<f:selectItems value="#{bean.countries}" var="country" itemValue="#{country.id}" itemLabel="#{country.name}" />
```

*(note that I renamed `Countries` model to `Country` and `getCountryId()` to `getId()` and `getCountryName()` to `getName()` since that makes more sense)*

#### See also:

- [Why JSF calls getters multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times/2090062#2090062)

Comment: ahh ive been doing it wrong this whole time. Thanks this works great and my application is 20x faster.

Answer (score 2):

take list out at class's field , initialize it in `@postconstruct` , in get method check if its null create it and return it or else return it,

Comment: Correct, but nullcheck in getter is unnecessary.

Comment: So I put   List<Countries> c_list = myDao.getCountryList(); in my @PostConstruct? I am confused as to what I should load in there

Comment: yes you are correct, just take list at class field, as shown by @BalusC